# Postgres array aggregate duplicate values in JSON_OBJECT_AGG

Tags: postgresql

I have a question/answer type architecture with three tables (`questions`, `question_responses`, `user_question_responses`)

I'm trying to build a object out of those responses with this query:

```
SELECT 
  json_object_agg(q.question_key,qr.value)
FROM user_question_responses uqr
JOIN question_responses qr ON qr.id = uqr.response_id
JOIN questions q ON q.id = uqr.question_id
WHERE uqr.user_id = $1
```

Which produces an object with duplicate keys:

```
{ 
  "is_active" : "No", 
  "desired_role" : "Front End", 
  "desired_role" : "Android", 
  "desired_role" : "Back End", 
  "experience" : "1 to 2 years", 
  "target_salary" : "$125,000 +", 
  "timezone" : "+/- 3 hours", 
  "type" : "Full-Time", 
  "type" : "Contractor"
}
```

Ideally I'd like to group the duplicate values into an array.

```
{ 
  "is_active" : "No", 
  "desired_role" : ["Front End", "Android", "Back End"],
  "experience" : "1 to 2 years", 
  "target_salary" : "$125,000 +", 
  "timezone" : "+/- 3 hours", 
  "type" : ["Full-Time", "Contractor"], 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t(a,b) as (values(1,2),(1,3),(2,4))
select
  json_object_agg(
    a,
    case
      when array_length(b,1)=1 then to_json(b[1])
      else to_json(b)
    end)
from (
  select a, array_agg(b) as b
  from t
  group by a) as x;

┌──────────────────────────┐
│     json_object_agg      │
├──────────────────────────┤
│ { "1" : [2,3], "2" : 4 } │
└──────────────────────────┘
```